# Finding multicollinearity from data with missing values

Tags: missing-data, multicollinearity

I have a data frame with around ~30 columns and at least 20 features have missing data in between 60-70%. I am wondering if it is possible to calculate multicollinearity in this case. If yes, how? My data looks like the following.

```
> head(df,2)
      age            income homeowner_status_desc marital_status_cd gender           education race_desc lang_desc child_in_hshld_flag
1    <NA> $35,000 - $49,999                  <NA>              <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     Other     Other                <NA>
2 35 - 44 $35,000 - $49,999                  Rent            Single      F High School Diploma  European   English                   N
  zip5_cd acct_type acct_type_primary birth_year birth_month experian_match insert_date child_age_0_3 child_age_4_6 child_age_7_9
1      NA        NA                NA         NA          NA           <NA>  2014-12-02          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
2      NA        NA                NA       1975           1              Y  2014-12-02             N             N             N
  child_age_10_12 child_age_13_15 child_age_16_18 dwelling_type  home_value residence occupation interest_automotive computer_owner
1            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>          <NA>        <NA>      <NA>       <NA>                <NA>           <NA>
2            <NA>               N               N Single Family 0 - 200,000   10 - 25       <NA>                   Y              Y
  interest_travel interest_fitness interest_home_decor interest_outdoors interest_sports interest_sports_propensity contributes_to_charities
1            <NA>             <NA>                  NA              <NA>            <NA>                         NA                     <NA>
2               Y             <NA>                  NA                 Y               Y                          0                     <NA>
  contrib_to_charity_propensity purchased_via_mail purchased_via_mail_propensity hitech_owner investor purchase_via_online
1                            NA               <NA>                            NA         <NA>     <NA>                <NA>
2                             4                  Y                             0            Y        Y                   Y
  purchase_via_online_propensity internet_online_subscriber child_in_hshld_count   mosaic_z4 segment
1                             NA                       <NA>                 <NA>        <NA>       N
2                              0                          Y                 <NA> Town Elders       N
```

Comment: You could certainly look at the complete cases rather easily.

Comment: Then I will be left with ~5% of the original data

Comment: That's if you delete all observations with at least one missing value though, correct?  Think of a complete case as any *pair* $(x_{ij}, x_{ik})$ where neither element is missing, and estimate each covariance using all the complete cases.  You may also want to try to learn about the cause of the missingness since it's conceivable that this could bias estimation of the covariances.